# LinearLayout TextView weight breaks with long text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

When i add long text to my `TextView` in linear layout it takes up all the space, and other views get squeezed. I set `layout_width="0"` to every view but it did not help. I should also add that this layout is used in `RecyclerView`.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="100">

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Lp"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

//this TextView takes all the space if text is long, but it behaves normally if text is short
<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/nazwa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Końcówka Yankauer do odsysania pola operacyjnego CH 23 (4 otwory boczne) z kontrolą odsysania" 
    android:layout_weight="20"/>

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ilosc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="#"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/jednostka"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="JM"
    android:layout_weight="15" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/cenaNetto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="C. net."
    android:layout_weight="15" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/wartNetto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="W.net."
    android:layout_weight="15" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/wartVAT"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="VAT"
    android:layout_weight="10" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/wartBrutto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="W. brut."
    android:layout_weight="15" />

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Here is a print screen of what breaks in my app [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SKeY.png)

Comment: why you are using height "match_parent" for all textViews?

Comment: Because if i don't it looks ugly like [this](http://i.imgur.com/e98BEBl.png)

Comment: If you want to give percentage vise view than try to new concept of android PercentRelativeLayout [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: @ashish I decided to go with your solution, it helped with my problem, but now my view looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/cWJIvI8.png). Does anyone know how to make all textViews same height as the biggest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below link code as a demo I hope you will get your result.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:shrinkColumns="*"
             android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_my_booking_unit_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
            </TextView>
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_my_booking_unit_quantity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
            </TextView>
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_my_booking_unit_amount"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, everything seems to be working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in your `TextView`?

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Yes, but the layout still looks same way, only with less text visible.

Comment: @musztardus is your `RecyclerView` horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want each textview to occupy same space then you can assign layout_weight=1 for all.

Comment: but i don't want each view to occupy same space. I want every view to occupy set percentage of space and it works, but if i set too long text in one of text views it breaks.